# Returning Subclass of generic superclass in a superclass method

Tags: java, generics

I am new to Java coming from a PHP background so sorry if this maybe obvious. I'm trying to implement a binary tree class and I've created an ADT like so:

```
public abstract class BTree<T> {
    private T value;
    private BTree<T> leftChild;
    private BTree<T> rightChild;
    private BTree<T> parent;
    public BTree<T> getLeftChild() { return this.leftChild; }
    ....
}
```

Then I have another class that extends this like so:

```
public class BIntTree extends BTree<Integer> {
}
```

However I want to be able to within BIntTree to have a method where I can call `this.getLeftChild();` and get an instance of BIntTree back rather than a instance of `BTree<Integer>`

Is this possible with some way of defining the generic class / method or do I have to explicitly type cast it after I used this.getLeftChild() or even override the superclass method?

My current solution is to explicitly typecast it in the BIntTree method with `BIntTree b=(BIntTree) this.getLeftChild();` which seems untidy to me.

Also I'm not so sure what would happen if I had that type casting defined and getLeftChild() returned null, would an exception be thrown? If so how do I cure this given that null is also a valid value if exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to have a self-typed class, but you have to wonder why you want it.  Why do you need to know that it is a `BIntTree` rather than a `BTree<Integer>`?  What have you gained with your use of generics?

Anyway, you could do something like this:

```
public abstract class BTree<V, T extends BTree<V, T>> {
    public T getLeft() {...}
    public T getRight() {...}
    public V getValue() {...}
}
```

Then your `BIntTree` would be

```
public class BIntTree extends BTree<Integer, BIntTree> {
    //...
}
```

### Edit

With regards to your question about casting `null`, there is really nothing preventing you from testing the behaviour yourself.  But to answer your question, it is safe to cast `null` to any type.

Comment: The specific declaration seems to be invalid: Eclipse compiler returns _Incorrect number of arguments for type BTree<V,T>; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <V>_ Am I missing something? if it is self-typed class, would the abstract class declaration be BTree<V, T extends BTree<V,T>> ?

Comment: @Ronald: Yep, you're right I omitted that by accident.  I've fixed it now but don't have a compiler handy to test it.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you and by far the most elegant solution in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would imagine that you'd want to make `value`, `leftChild`, `rightChild`, and `parent` protected, not private, so that they can be accessed from the subclass.

Once you make that change, you can have `BIntTree.getLeftChild()` return a `BTree<Integer>` simply by defining your subclass as follows:

```
public class BIntTree extends BTree<Integer> {
    public BTree<Integer> getLeftChild() { return this.leftChild; }
    ...
}
```

I'll just add that you should only really be defining such a class if you have some `Integer`-specific logic happening here.  Otherwise, it would make sense to leave the type of `T` up to whoever uses your `BTree` class.

Answer (score 1):

You can override required method like this:

```
public class BIntTree extends BTree<Integer> {
    @Override
    public BIntTree getLeftChild() { return (BIntTree) super.getLeftChild(); } 
}
```

As of vertion 1.5 Java supports covariant return types - meaning you can return type with it's subclass.

Comment: You'd still be stuck with the cast though.